# Computational complexity of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-complexity

> **True or False:** Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be two matrices. Computing the product $AB \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ takes roughly $d^2$ floating point operations.

I'm having a hard time computing floating point operations. I believe the above is false but I am not sure how do you show it. How do you compute FLOPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Well, the naive way of computing the product of two matrices $C = AB$ defines
$$
c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^d a_{ik} b_{kj}.
$$

1. How many operations (multiplications and additions) are needed to compute one such $c_{ij}$?
2. How many entries do you need to compute?

Multiply the answers from (1) and (2) and you get the number of floating point operations needed.

Can you now complete this?

---

**UPDATE**

Following your comments, you (almost) got it correctly. Note that
$$
c_{ij} = a_{i1}b_{1k} + a_{i2}b_{2k} + \ldots + a_{d1}b_{dk},
$$
and each term in the sum needs $1$ multiplication to be computed, which is $d$ multiplications total, as you note. Now there will be $d$ numbers to add, but that requires $d-1$ multiplications (it takes $1$ operation to add $2$ numbers, $2$ operations to add $3$ numbers, etc.).

Overall, computing one entry is $d+(d-1) =2d-1$ operations, and we have $d^2$ entries in the matrix, so a total of $d^2(2d-1) =\Theta(d^3)$ calculations.

Comment: As you highlighted, there are two operations (multiplication and addition) to compute one $c_{ij}$ and there are d entires, so the number of floating point operations is 2d?

Comment: @codelearner the sum has $d$ elements, so you need $d$ multiplications and $d-1$ additions to compute $c_{ij}$

Comment: I think I got it. Each cell has two operations which is multiplication and addition. There are d multiplications and d - 1 additions which equates to about 2d in each cell. The matrix is $dxd$ which = to $d^2$. So 2d*$d^2$ is $2d^3$. Am I right? I am just not sure about the d-1 addition and d multiplication which gets us 2d. Not sure how does that work?

Comment: @codelearner please see the update, you almost got it